# Selenium opens sites with certificate error

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver, certificate-error

In this question I'll talk about python package selenium on mac arm

Before google has realised 115 version of chrome, chrome driver & selenium worked fine and all sites opened without any issues. But now there appears certificate error. I know that `options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')` will help with openning, but it won't fix the main issue - connection will be insecure. I need to fix it, because some sites could work differently with and without this error.

I wonder, if someone could help me with it. I actually tried reinstalling (update) google chrome, chrome driver, seleniumwire, undetected_chromedriver and even python... Also now I install 110 version of chrome.

Sorry for bad english

Comment: What happens if you visit those pages yourself, from the browser?

Comment: @tevemadar It will be ok, without any issue. And with selenium it will happen with all sites (google, steampowered, youtube, stackoverflow and e.t.c)